# Is there a way to Move a VSE Strip without moving its Keyframes?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, graph-editor

In the VSE, is there a way to slide a Strip (audio file in this case) left-or-right on the time axis without moving the Keyframes I've made for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the NLA Editor you can do one of the following:

- [Created a NLA-Strip](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Rking/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/NLA#Creating_Action_Strips) by clicking the [image: snowflake icon] next to your action.
- Temporarily unlink the the datablock in the [Animation Data panel](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Rking/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/NLA#Animation_Data) while you preforming the transformation.